# Sum is not small with overwhelming probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

Given only a bound of the form $P(|X_i| < c_1) < 1 - c_2$ for some fixed small $c_1, c_2 > 0$, does there exist $c>0$ such that

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i| < \varepsilon n\right) = O(e^{-cn})$$
for sufficiently small $\epsilon$?  Here the $X_i$ are iid.

The probability that *all* of the $|X_i|$ are less than $\varepsilon$ is $(1-c_2)^n$, but I do not see how to get an exponentially small bound on the *average* being less than $\varepsilon$.

This comes from Exercise 2 of Terence Tao's blog post [254A Notes 7: The Least Singular Value](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/254a-notes-7-the-least-singular-value/)

Comment: this is Cramers theorem as long as I understood.

Comment: But I need to prove that it is unlikely the sum is small, not large.

Comment: it depends on the value of $\varepsilon$ it is really small if $\varepsilon$ is larger than the mean of $|X|$ and it is not small otherwise. I hope I dont remember the other way around. Cramers theorem explains the details.

Comment: I see. So the point of the bound in the first line is to get that $E|X| \ge c_2 c_1$ by Markov's inequality, and then the average concentrates around $E|X|$ on the scale of $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ by CLT, and for $\varepsilon$ much smaller than $c_2 c_1$, the average is less than $\varepsilon$ with exponentially small probability by Cramer.